# If Hardy proved that there are infinite zeros lying on the critical line, does not that mean he proved the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

This is an exerpt of the wiki page covering Riemann Hypothesis:

*" Thus, if the hypothesis is correct, **all the non-trivial zeros** lie on the critical line consisting of the complex numbers 
 + i t, where t is a real number and i is the imaginary unit. " *

When they say "all", it means that all the non-trivial must lie on the critical line, and Hardy proved that there are infinite zeros of that type ( i.e $Re(s) =\frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: There are infinitely many prime numbers....that does not show that every integer is prime.

Comment: Consider the following example: "There are infinitely many even numbers, but that doesn't mean all numbers are even."

Comment: @lulu , this means that there infinite zeros, but they are not non-trival?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker should review basic logic before dwelling into analytic number theory.

Comment: Think your question through.  It's one thing for someone to assert that all swans are white, quite another to assert that there are lots of white swans.

Comment: No - in principle, you could have infinitely many nontrivial zeroes on the critical line *and* a bunch of nontrivial zeroes *not* on the line!

Comment: Everybody tip-toes around those _non-trivial_ zeroes, that's funny. It's a curious idiom, because the _trivial_ zeroes (all negative even integers) are those which are just there because of the functional equation for the Zeta function, which is highly non-trivial. The "trivial" zeroes don't seem to play a role in the distribution of primes, but they are not meaningless.

Comment: The [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) is that $|\psi(x)-x| < C x^{1/2} \log^2 x$ and the functional equation of $\zeta(s)$ tells us if there is a zero at $s=\rho$ then $|\psi(x) -x |$ is not $< C |x^{\rho}|$

Comment: @ProfessorVector The trivial zeros are meaningless in the sense there are Dirichlet series with the same trivial zeros (functional equation) but for which the RH fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: remember that there are infinitely many even integers, but there are also infinitely many odd integers. Equally, there are infinitely many primes, but "most" integers are not prime.

Hardy's proof shows there are infinitely many on the critical line, but says nothing about what proportion are. By proportion, we mean 
$$\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{\text{number of zeros with real part $1/2$ and imaginary part between $0$ and $T$}}{\text{number of zeros in critical strip with imaginary part between $0$ and $T$}}.$$
(the even number-integer analogue has proportion half, for example: half of integers are even. On the other hand, there are about $n/\log{n}$ primes less than $n$, so the proportion of positive integers that are prime is zero.)
The best estimate on the proportion that lie on the critical line was provided by [Conrey (1989)](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002206781).

Comment: Thank you @Chappers. I get it now.